# How to read from properties file and get values in wsdl file java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

In my soap webservice java project i have a properties file in the class path for reading some constants in the project. Its a non maven project, all jars are added directly to the lib folder. Here i want to read from properties file and refer those keys in wsdl file, which is inside WEB-INF folder. How can i add those key in the wsdl file to get the values inside it. Please help and many thanks in advance for your valuable replys.

Answer (score 0):

it's not that hard, you can do it like that:

you have a config.properties file which contains :

```
database=xxxx
dbuser=myusername
dbpassword=xxxxx
IP= 192.xxxxxx
```

When you want now to get the username you do :

```
private static Properties prop;
private String username;
prop = new Properties();
username = prop.getProperty("username"); // you get myusername
```

Comment: Thats the way to read properties file in java class.. my requirement is to call it inside wsdl file.

Comment: Properties file is already loaded in the classpath and im using the same in my java classes. But i want to get it inside wsdl. Please text me the syntax to call inside wsdl.

Comment: ah ok the question was not very clear, the best way is to use a maven profile instead of a property file.

Comment: Otherwise please share your code to help solving that problem

Comment: <soap:address location="${wsdl.url}"/>
I tried to read like above in wsdl file. But it failed. 

Its not a maven project. Is there any alternate way to read it.

Comment: I don't know a way to do this, maybe someone have a solution for this.